# Big O $n^{1/n}$ = Big Theta(1)?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am trying to prove if $n^{1/n}$ = Big Theta(1)

Is it sufficient to say that if we let c = n, then $n^{1/n}$ <= $n*1$

And if we let c = $1/n^{1/n}$, then $1$ <= ($1/n^{1/n}$)/$n^{1/n}$

I'm not sure if this is completely true because in all the examples I've seen of Big Theta, the c is always a constant value

Comment: Not sufficient. Note that $2^n\gt n$ (induction, if you need to prove). Taking $n$-th roots we get $n^{1/n}\lt 2$. And of course $n^{1/n}\ge 1$.

Comment: Sorry why of course $n^{1/n}$ >= 1?

Comment: Any positive power of a number $\ge 1$ is $\ge 1$. Or if you want, if we had $n^{1/n}\lt 1$, then taking the $n$-th power we would get $n\lt 1$, which is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitions of "Big Theta" vary in inessential ways. I will use $f(n)=\Theta(1)$ if there are positive constants $c$ and $C$ such that for large enough $n$ we have $c\le f(n)\le C$.

From the definition, you can see that it is not enough to show that $n^{1/n}\lt n$ for all $n$, since  $n$ is not a constant.

Now for the proof that $n^{1/n}=\Theta(1)$.

For a lower bound $c$, note that $n^{1/n}\ge 1$ for every positive integer $n$.

For an upper bound $C$, recall (or prove) that $2^n\gt n$ for every positive integer $n$. Taking $n$-th roots we find that $2\gt n^{1/n}$.